# Span inside Anchor with event bubbling

Tags: jquery, onclick, event-bubbling

I have such a piece of html:

```
<li class="addToFriends"><a href="....">Something something<span>INSIDE SPAN</span>something</a></li>
```

To handle AJAX request when clicking on anchor I have registered handler on click event:

```
    $('.addToFriends a').click(function(event){
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('a')) {
              // if I click on SPAN element following fragment won't execute!


      // do ajax request
    }       
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

My questions are:

- why click event is raised for span element? After all, I didn't bind click event to SPAN elements
- apart from previous question, I thought that if I won't handle SPAN click event, browser will use event-bubbling to raise click event for anchor (if I won't call event.stopPropagation()). But I also didn't work out for me as that click event is raised only once

So now, I got round that problem I my solution is:

```
    $('.addToFriends a').click(function(event){
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (!target.is('a')) {
      target = target.parent('a')
    } 
            ...
});
```

But still, I'm curious why it works like this...

Thanks,

Paweł

Comment: Thanks, I will take a closer look into specification & article. Anyway, meaby you could answer that question: > why click event is raised for span
> element? After all, I didn't bind
> click event to SPAN elements because, mainly this is an issue for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. After studing mentioned articles everything is crystal clear. And instead of refering to **e.target** (which can change) I refer to **this** (which is always anchor).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use the currentTarget of your event.

```
$('.addToFriends a').click(function(event){
     event.currentTarget;    
     ...
});
```

Comment: If I had read that answer more carefully I would have noticed that you suggested to use currentTarget instead of target. That was the solution in itself. How clusmy of me :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, but if I click on SPAN and call stopPropagation() method my code in that form won't work:

```
$('.addToFriends a').click(function(event){
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('a')) {
       // do ajax request
       event.stopPropagation();               
       event.preventDefault();
    }
```

});

Still, I thing I'm missing some crucial points related with event bubbling.

Answer (score 1):

You can always read the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html). A nice tutorial is also available [here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents).

StopPropagation has only meaning if you have defined click event handlers for both the SPAN and A elements. Calling the stopPropagation in the SPAN event handler will prevent the A handler from being called. This assumes the default bubble phase.